# Git merge não aconteceu como esperado

Tags: git, merge

Olá, vou tentar ser bem prático neste meu problema.

1 - Trabalhando no branch 'correcao' acabei realizando alterações de coisas distintas misturando coisas...

2 - Dai para tentar 'melhorar' criei um novo branch filho

```
git checkout -b correcao-banco
```

adicionei os arquivos específicos deste novo branch e commit!

3 - Dai voltei pro branch original

```
git checkout correcao
```

4 - Adicionei os arquivos restantes e commit!

Agora meu objetivo seria trazer para o master somente as correções do branch 'correcao' e nada do 'correcao-banco'.

5 - Fui para o master

```
git checkout master
```

6 - mandei ver o merge

```
git merge correcao
```

Dai aconteceu um merge que não foi feliz porque deu um fast forward e trouxe as alterações do 'correcao-banco' junto...

Pelo visto este é o comportamento esperado mas não pra mim... fiquei sem entender e agora? Tenho como voltar atrás para poder tirar as alterações do 'correcao-banco'?

Obrigado.

Comment: Se a resposta ajudou, nos sinalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O processo que você executou é o correto na sua intenção. [Conforme você pode checar neste exemplo extraído diretamente do Git SCM](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ramifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Branching-no-Git-B%C3%A1sico-de-Branch-e-Merge). Logo, o que pode ter ocorrido é que no momento que voltou para a branch `correcao`, ter levado também alguma alteração da branch `correcao-banco`.

Sobre voltar atrás, é possível reverter o `merge`:

```
# Revertendo commit de merge
git revert -m 1 <merge_commit_sha>
```

[Documentação do Git Revert.](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

Comment: Bom saber que processo que realizei é o correto, provavelmente devo ter feito alguma outra coisa 'errada' que não me lembro.